# Taylor Expansion of $\int_0^t\frac{1}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{2/3}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to taylor expand the following integral around $1$.
$$\int_0^t\frac{1}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{2/3}}$$
What I want to do is taylor expand around $1$ then integrate all the terms. Is this true? If so, what conditions do I have to check?

Comment: You forgot the $dx$.

Comment: Do you want to expand near $t=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(u) = \int_0^{1+u^3}\frac{dx}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{2/3}}$$
$$f ' (u)=\frac{3u^2}{(1+u^3)^{2/3}u^2}=\frac3{(1+u^3)^{2/3}}$$
$$\approx 3(1-\frac23u^3+\frac59u^6-...$$
$$f(u) \approx C + 3u-\frac12u^4+\frac5{21}u^7$$
$$\int_0^{1+t}\frac{dx}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{2/3}}\approx C+ 3t^{1/3}-\frac12t^{4/3}+\frac5{21}t^{7/3}-...$$

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a pole at $x=1$, you don't have a Taylor expansion there.  Your integral is improper at the lower limit and for any upper limit greater than or equal to $1$.

If you substitute $x= u+1/2$, the integrand becomes

$$\left(\frac{1}{4} - u^2 \right)^{-2/3}.$$

You can expand that with the binomial theorem and integrate term by term, but I don't think the series will converge at $u= \pm 1/2.$